# iPhones proximity sensor gives wrong data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, proximity, proximitysensor

I'd implement checking proximityState property that tells me if user have phone near his ear. Like he is making a phone call. In iOS 7 works, but then I had to remove this feauter due to other reasons. Now on iOS 8 I add this feature in app and efter the proximity change its state to YES for the first time in stays YES forever. It's not switched to NO not even when you remove the device from your ears. Looks like it kind of a bug in ios, has anybody else having this same issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. self.device.proximityState should be read on main thread. All the work was done in the background threat and if I check proximityState on main thread it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have not had this issue and the following code below works in iOS 8. Remember if the application does not support portrait mode, the proximity sensor will not be monitored.
My application's delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    UIDevice *currentDevice;
}

- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Application finished launching!");
    currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [currentDevice setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    if (currentDevice.proximityMonitoringEnabled)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onProximitySensorStateChanged:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        NSLog(@"Monitoring proximity sensor!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Device does not have a proximity sensor!");
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) onProximitySensorStateChanged: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    if (currentDevice.proximityState)
    {
        NSLog(@"User is now close to the proximity sensor!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"User is now away from the proximity sensor!");
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: I somehow found out that if I put proximityMonitoring ON during the call, than after the phone call it gets the rignt value.

Comment: Strange.  I called myself from another phone to test the code and it seemed to get the values correctly.

Comment: Yes, because your monitoring is always ON, if the monitoring is set to OFF during phone call it gives wrong proximityState after it gets back to app. I leave it ON during the call and that's it. In my app I dont want to have proximity checking always on, because if user cover proximity sensor by mistake it blacks out the screen which is bad user experiance.

Thanks for your help and your time, I respect that, realy.

Comment: No problem and from what I have seen so far its impossible to stop the proximity sensor from blacking the screen.  Best of luck though.